# Express.js and passport.js, but cannot get /login

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, passport.js

I'm trying to build an express app, but now I'm stuck at the login process. I'm not sure it has anything to do with the problem that I'm having, but my assignement for school said I had to use passport.js to make a login form.

So, the problem I'm having is that everytime I try to render my page in my browser on localhost:3000/login I get this message:

```
CANNOT GET /login
```

There are probably even more problems with my code, but since I already get this error, it's impossible to find out.

My default app file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Example listening on port 3000!')
});

const loginRoute = require('./routes/logins.js');

app.use('/login', loginRoute);

const passport = require('passport')
    , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));

module.exports = app;
```

My route/logins file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pug = require('pug');

const login = pug.compileFile('views/login.pug');

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', { title: 'Login' });
});

const passport = require('passport');

router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true })
);

module.exports = router;
```

My views/login.pug file:

```
 doctype html
html
    head
    body
        h1 #{title}
        form(action='/login', method='post')
            div
                label Username:
                input(type='text', name='username')
            div
                label Password:
                input(type='password', name='password')
            div
                input(type='submit', value='Log In')
```

If someone could help me with this, I would be very thankful.

Comment: can you try moving `app.listen` block to just above `module.exports = app;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are mounting your router onto the path `/login`, and then in your router you have:

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res){...})
```

Express will evaluate that as `localhost:3000/login/login`

The paths in the router files should be relavtive to the path you mount it on. So for `localhost:3000/login` your `logins` router should look like this

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){...})
//and
router.post('/', function(req, res){...})
```